# How can I see the transfer details when copying files from some external devices connected via USB with MTP (phone/GoPro) to some disk on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer, statistics, mtp

I don't see any transfer details when copying files from some external devices connected via USB with MTP (e.g., a phone or a GoPro) to some disk on Windows 10:

[image]

Typically I see transfer details:

[image]

How can I see the transfer details when copying files from some external devices connected via USB (e.g., a phone or a GoPro) to some disk on Windows 10?

I use Windows Explorer for file transfers.

Comment: Most likely you cannot, because the less detailed window is for an MTP transfer, which is fundamentally different from regular block storage access.

Comment: @DanielB thanks, good point, indeed MTP

Comment: One option would be to use `resmon`. It might not be very precise, considering that you can only check the transfers on the target disk, but it might give you a good idea of the current speed.